# Error con el uso de Accessor en Chrome - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome

Me podrian ayudar con este error que me arroja Chrome:

El ERROR que me arroja es este --> Uncaught TypeError: Accessor properties are not allowed.

```
*jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Accessor properties are not allowed.
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at Storage.value (script.js:139)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (script.js:91)
    at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)*
```

Acá esta el codigo de mis funciones:

```
// Functions
// object.watch
if (!Object.prototype.watch) {
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "watch", {
      enumerable: false
    , configurable: true
    , writable: false
    , value: function (prop, handler) {
        var
          oldval = this[prop]
        , newval = oldval
        , getter = function () {
            return newval;
        }
        , setter = function (val) {
            oldval = newval;
            return newval = handler.call(this, prop, oldval, val);
        }
        ;

        if (delete this[prop]) { // can't watch constants
            Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
                  get: getter
                , set: setter
                , enumerable: true
                , configurable: true
            });
        }
    }
});
}

  // object.unwatch
  if (!Object.prototype.unwatch) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "unwatch", {
      enumerable: false
    , configurable: true
    , writable: false
    , value: function (prop) {
        var val = this[prop];
        delete this[prop]; // remove accessors
        this[prop] = val;
    }
});
}
```

En firefox/mozilla no me arroja este error y sin problemas manejo estas funciones y accessors!!!
Alguien sabrá porque pasa?.

Gracias!!!

Comment: Es posible que el problema esté en tu **versión de Chrome**. En la documentación oficial indican que se presenta un bug en 37 y anteriores `Chrome 37 (and below) has a bug where an attempt to define a "prototype" property, on a function, with writable: false doesn't work as expected.` ver: [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Comment: @quevedo  tengo la ultima version de chrome Version 86.0.4240.75......no es ese el problema. Gracias de todos modos